# Profiling .NET core tests

Tags: testing, .net-core, profiling

The test suite I am executing is taking long time to finish. The suite is mainly integration tests involving database.

I'd like to find out possible bottlenecks and shorten the test execution time.

The tests can be started from the commandline using `dotnet test Solution.sln` and when I try to profile it (using either JetBrains dotTrace or `dotnet-trace` (`dotnet-trace collect -- dotnet test Solution.sln`) it is only profiling the dotnet process and not my code.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks